# Using JavaScript replace() in Vue.js causing errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a string where I want to remove all characters including slashes etc and just keep the numbers. I have tried using the following which was previously working on another project:

```
myString.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, "")
```

But when using this in Vue I get the following errors:

```
error  Unnecessary escape character: \D  no-useless-escape
error  Unnecessary escape character: \s  no-useless-escape
error  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape
error  Unnecessary escape character: \-  no-useless-escape
```

Why is this happening?

The string is provided by an input where the user is supposed to enter a value. So when getting the value I need to make sure that I only get the integers with its decimal value if present. I know I could set the type of the input to number to make sure the value is an integer but I need it to be of type text for my project.

The values entered would typically look like this if formatted correctly:

```
£100,000
£10,036.96
£999.90
£90.6
£0.5
```

Desired output:

```
100000
10000.96
999.9
90.6
0.5
```

But the user may accidentally enter other characters than above so I need to remove anything other than the integers with its decimal point for example:

input

```
£hf79.90
```

desired output

```
79.9
```

Comment: `[` and `]` contain a character set, you're supposed to put actual characters in there, not reg ex syntax. The Vue linter assumes you mean to write `D` and `s`, `.` and `-` as in those literal characters, and complains about the useless backslashes. To remove all non-digits, simply replace `/\D/g`

Comment: @ChrisG Would I be albe to make it so that it also still keeps the decimals as well as the numbers? Just noticed I'll be needing it

Comment: Please provide input examples and desired output.

Comment: So you probably want this: `/[^0-9.]/g`, it's a negated set matching everything except digits and periods.